# Continuous extension from the closure of a tetrahedron to unit ball.

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}^3$ with usual topology let $B$ be the closed unit ball and $T$ be the closure of  tetrahedron inscribed  $B$, let $f:T\to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function, I need to know which of the following is true?

1. $f$ has continous extension to $B\Rightarrow f$ is constant function.
2. $f$ has no ingeneral cont.extension to $b$.
3. $f$ has always cont. extension to $B$.
4. If $f$ has cont. extension to $B$ then $f(T)\subseteq [0,1]$

closure of any set is closed so by Titze's Extension Theorem I can get an continuous extension. so only $3$ is true?

Answer (score 1):

The question is posed in a very confusing fashion (I'm accustomed to tetrahedrons that include their boundaries), but yes, Tietze's Extension Theorem gets you the answer immediately. That said, the situation here is geometrically very nice (pleasantly-shaped subsets of $\Bbb R^n$), so you should probably be able to get a much more explicit extension.